# Graphql architecture

Tags: mongodb, express, graphql, graphql-js

In the new year, I want to learn how to use GraphQL. Why not using this technology for personal project or at work. So, for now I will use it with MongoDB at backend and VueJS 2.0 at frontend.

I have a question about how to send query and mutations. Do I need to send directly query like :

```
query {
    posts {
        _id
        title
        content
    }
}
```

and mutations from client-side (write it at client side) and send it to server endpoint ? (it is secure ?) .

else I was thinking about writing all my queries at backend and simply request post request with action param like `QUERY_POST` and at backend I find my query for `QUERY_POST` and play GraphQL query and send it at vue-side.

What did you think, what is the best way ? I'm a little lost about it. Storing queries and mutations at client side or at server-side ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit confusing... the whole point of GraphQL is the capability to request everything you need (and nothing more) in 1 query. A mutation is a specific type of query which will modify data on your back-end. GraphQL queries are to be issued by the client.

After this is your responsibility on server-side to implement authentication and access control so that your data is not exposed to the world.

If you are new to GraphQL, I recommend you to have a look at this excellent tutorial: https://learngraphql.com/basics/querying-graphql

You may be interested in https://www.graph.cool/ too.

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

Often you will send the query in the request body using something like Apollo Client, Relay, or some other networking library. Here is an example you could run from your vue app.

Here is a full tutorial & starter kit that can help you get started :)

https://github.com/kristianmandrup/vue2-apollo-scaphold